# How to select rows from database based on username?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

How do you select only rows that apply to the user currently signed in when using the Configure Data Source dialog? Right each row has a username that was created for them when they register. I am using the built in ASP.NET membership system. Is there anyway to do a Where clause that selects the current users username?

Comment: You need to get current Logined User Name ? Can you please provide details what you actually need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

gives you the windows user name associated with the current request.

To get it into your where clause you have to add a parameter to the select command

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="Select * From tbl Where user = @user">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="user" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and then set the value in code behind:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["user"].DefaultValue = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

There might be other ways to get it there but this should be one of the easiest.

Microsofts article for using parameters on the datasource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.aspx) to the `SqlDataSource` control.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the parameters to the sql datasource for extracting the username and password from the database.

or you can create one stored proceduce to select the username and password.
and then pass the values of username and password in code behind.